# Trouble decoding some special characters &#146; &#147; &#148;

Tags: php, utf-8, html-entities, html-encode

I'm trying to decode some special characters in php and can't seem to find a way to do it.

```
 $str = 'Thi&#146;s i"s a&#146;n e&#148;xa&#147;mple';
```

This just returns some dots.

```
$str = preg_replace_callback("/(&#[0-9]+;)/", function($m) {
    return mb_convert_encoding($m[1], "UTF-8", "HTML-ENTITIES");
}, $str);
```

Some other tests just return the same string.

```
$str = html_entity_decode($str, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
$str = htmlspecialchars_decode($str, ENT_QUOTES);
```

Anyway, I've been trying all sorts of combinations but really no idea how to convert this to UTF-8 characters.

What I'm expecting to see is this:

```
Thi’s i"s a’n e”xa“mple
```

And actually if I take this directly and use `htmlentities` to encode it I see different characters to begin with.

```
Thi&rsquo;s i&quot;s a&rsquo;n e&rdquo;xa&ldquo;mple
```

Unfortunately I don't have control of the source and I'm stuck dealing with those characters.

Are they non standard, do I need to replace them manually with my own lookup table?

**EDIT**

Looking at this table here: https://brajeshwar.github.io/entities/

I see the characters I'm looking after are not listed. When I test a few characters from this table they decode just fine. I guess the list in php is incomplete by default?

Comment: I'm getting the expected result with all three methods...

Comment: html_entity_decode works fine.  What version of php are you using?  When you write "what I'm expecting to see"  what does that mean?

Comment: `’` is not the unicode codepoint 146 (U+0092) but U+2019. Even if it works for someone somewhere - it's just a coincidence, and in general should now work.

Comment: @PhillipWeber you re getting this `Thi’s i"s a’n e”xa“mple` from `Thi&#146;s i"s a&#146;n e&#148;xa&#147;mple` ?

Comment: @gview I'm using 7.1. It means I'm expecting to see the line I have right after that sentence `Thi’s i"s a’n e”xa“mple`.

Comment: @zerkms I agree, seems non standard and not supported in php by default, but maybe by some other library that happens to be installed. I'm wondering if there are some sample tables out there I can use? (perhaps I should have mentioned it's php).

Comment: @Rob it's not that it's not "supported by php", those glyphs simply don't exist. Apparently, they were taken from cp1250 and not properly re-encoded.

Comment: @zerkms yes, I see what you mean now, thx.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you check the unicode standard for the characters you're referring to: http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U0080.pdf

You would see that all the codepoints you have in your string do not have representable glyphs and are control characters.

Which means that it is expected that they are rendered as empty squares (or dots, depending on how your renderer treats those).

If it works for someone somewhere - it's a non-standard behaviour, which one must not rely on, since it is, well, non-standard.

Apparently the text you have has the initial encoding of cp1250, so you either should treat it accordingly, or re-encode entities manually:

```
$str = 'Thi&#146;s i"s a&#146;n e&#148;xa&#147;mple';

$str = preg_replace_callback("/&#([0-9]+);/u", function($m) {
    return iconv('cp1250', 'utf-8', chr($m[1]));
}, $str);

echo $str;
```

Comment: Put the original string in an HTML document. That's where you'll see the output OP is after

Comment: @Phil just because it is rendered in some way by some apps does not mean those characters have glyphs. Browsers forgive a lot of mistakes and try to be helpful.

Comment: Oh, I just meant that it wasn't too hard to be that *"someone, somewhere"*

Comment: Where did you get that &#8217 code from? Is there a link to a table of these I could use?

Comment: @Rob I just copied the `’` character from your expected output and checked its code (in my case the quickest way to do that is with js: `'’'.charCodeAt(0)`)

Comment: @zerkms ok, I see. I found some table for it [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1250) so I will just do a manual mapping from this, thx!